# "request invite" gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, rubygems, invite

I am looking for a gem that will allow users to request an invite, and also allow me to batch release invites to people.

Currently, I am using Devise for authentication, and am planning on allowing users who have activated accounts to invite a small amount of others, but I need a system that will allow them to request an invite in the first instance.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like devise_invitable may be what you need for the bit that allows users to invite others.

https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable

Here's a post that explains how to achieve what you seem to be describing using devise_invitable.

http://andrewgertig.com/2011/03/making-your-rails-web-app-invite-only-using-devise_invitable/

I don't know of any gems that handle the 'requesting an invite' part but isn't this relatively straightforward if you set up a mechanism for collecting email addresses and then use devise_invitable to send out invitations to these email addresses from a site admin?